# Changing node version from node@16 to node@14 on Mac OS

Tags: terminal, homebrew, upgrade, path

I‘m using brew. As I need an older version of `node` I

- installed node@14 (`brew install node@14`)
- unlinked the recent version (`brew unlink node`)
- linked the old version that I want (`brew link node@14`)

At the end it says

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

so I ran that command and then I checked the node version (`node --version`) and it shows (v16.13.0) so nothing changed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a new Terminal window?

Comment: Modifying a shell configuration does not reload that configuration.  Restart the shell, usually by opening a new terminal window.  Further, unless you need both of them, why didn't you just uninstall the one you didn’t need?

Comment: I just opened  a new terminal window and it worked :,) thank u

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` caches paths it used to call a binary, so if you have run the `node` from that Terminal tab before it will still use v16. Run `hash -r` to remove all cached entries or open a new Terminal tab/window.

Comment: a new window solved it